# rename file by adding a value using bash

Tags: bash, find, rename, filenames

I have a series of files with similar extension in a directory and it's subdirectories. I'd like to add a constant value to their integer part of the basename. Is there any way to do it using Bash? Let's take following example.

Before:
../ParentDirectory/Directory/123-File.ext

after adding 20 to the integer part (123+20=143):
../ParentDirectory/Directory/143-File.ext

I assume a series of FIND and RENAME commands are needed, but I'm not sure how!

Comment: You can do this with the perl-based `rename` command, because it allows calculations in its regular expression replacement operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- The top directory is "ParentDirectory" and its subdirectories
  contain the files to be renamed.
- The files have extension ".ext".
- The filenames start with the number and do not contain other numbers
  in the middle of the filenames.

Then would you please try the `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find ParentDirectory -type f -name "*.ext" | while IFS= read -r path; do
    dir=${path%/*}              # extract the directory name
    fname=${path##*/}           # extract the file name
    num=${fname//[^0-9]/}       # number part of the file name
    remain=${fname//[0-9]/}     # remaining part of the file name
    (( num += 20 ))             # add 20 to the number
    newpath="$dir/$num$remain"  # compose the new filename
    if [[ -f $newpath ]]; then  # make sure the new filename doesn't duplicate
        echo "$newpath already exists. skip renaming."
    else
        echo mv -- "$path" "$newpath"
                                # print the mv command
    fi
done
```

It outputs the `mv` commands as a dry run. If the output looks good,
drop `echo` before `mv` command and run again.

As Barmar suggests, if `perl rename` command is available, please try
instead:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's/\d+(?!.*\/)/$& + 20/e' ParentDirectory/**/*.ext
```

- The regex `\d+(?!.*\/)` matches number *not* followed by a slash.
  It avoids to match numbers included in the directory names.
- The `e` modifier at the end of the `rename` command tells `perl`
  to evaluate the substitution `$& + 20` as a perl expression
  rather than a literal substitution string.
- `ParentDirectory/**/*.ext` is expanded recursively due to the
  `shopt -s globstar` option.
- The `-n` option just prints the filenames with no action. If the output looks good, drop `-n`.

Please note there are two different `rename` commands: "perl rename"
and "non-perl rename" depending on the distribution. You can determine
which one is installed by taking a look of `man rename`. If it
includes the word `Perl`, it is the `perl rename` command.